# What is the best solution for calling rest service again after some intervals ? Angular/TS

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to call a rest service, if service return error code then I want to call that service again after 5 seconds else not ?

Answer (score 1):

I thing what you want is to retry . The best way to handle this using the new `HttpClient` and `retry` [link](https://angular.io/guide/http#retry).

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';

Then, you can use it with HTTP Observables like this:

http
  .get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items')
  // Retry this request up to 3 times.
  .retry(3)
  // Any errors after the 3rd retry will fall through to the app.
  .subscribe(...);
```

But if you still want to keep on hitting the db till it gives a response go with.

> Note - this is not a good way to handle error and leads to performance
>   issues

```
setInterval(function() {
  // method to be executed;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: thanks for this, I would like to process the response and then repeat the service again if response code in body is not what I expect. 


imagine I get "status: 1" instead of 0 so I would like to try again

Comment: This is something else not a error response right?. For this you need to use observables

Comment: yes, response is always 200 and appropriate body, I just  need to call service again if status in response is not expected with some time interval.

Comment: So inside the subscribe you can check using if the response status is other than 200 then insode that if using set Interval call that very method again after some time gap. That will work i suppose

Comment: I was able to do this with intervals and **takeWhile** -taking value from the observable and processing in it